# Как предотвратить наложение div друга на друга при смещении?

Tags: css, css3

Надо сделать так, чтобы если у дива есть что-то вроде `top: 50%` или `margin-top:60vh`, то если есть элементы ниже, он не накладывался на них, а был просто над ними

> P.S. Вопрос очень интересен и я прошу развернутый, грамотный ответ. Через 2 дня отправлю на премию и чей ответ будет лучшим, отмечу

Чтобы меньше `js` и больше css, плюс fallback для древних браузеров типа ie7

Comment: Если у `div` по умолчанию `position: static;`, то `margin-top: 60vh` не будет заставлять накладываться на элементы ниже.

Comment: Что бы не накладывалось друг на друга при смещении очевидно надо смещать всё вместе.

Comment: @Sergey это же очевидно, вопрос в том как именно это сделать.

Comment: Там 50% прибавили и там прибавляйте. Или разместите всё в общий div контейнер и двигайте его одного. А при стандартном позиционировании всё само двигается. Зависит от Вашего html-я.

Comment: @sergey А если у меня общий див `height: 100%` `max-height: 100%` и мне надо логитип посередине, и снизу элемент, который прилиплен к низу, и надо чтобы логотип не наезжал на него

Comment: Раз посередине и скорее всего середина вертикальная, есть нижний элемент, значит есть и верхний? Средний с логотипом вставляется в разрыв между верхним и нижним или закрывает верхний, сидя на нижнем? Почему бы не обрисовать ситуацию полностью, рисунки какие-нибудь приложить? Может кто-нибудь и скажет что дельное, а так какой вопрос, такие и комментарии в общих чертах.